# How to keep a wall power supply from dyeing?

Tags: power-supply

I recently had a 12v 1200mA wall power supply that I was playing with. I was making a aluminum can cutter using gator clamps and .7 pencil lead (graphite) it was ok for about 10 minutes but then I shorted out my power supply. Can someone tell me how I can stop it from frying my power supply???or do I have to makes bench power supply out of it? 
      My idea : connect a appropriate resistor and a diode to my power supply. Or maybe and a fuse or ground

Comment: Such a power supply is unsuited to use in experiments where you can possibly overload it. What you need is a power supply with **current limiting**. Most proper bench supplies have this. You could also calculate the lowest load your supply can manage, in this case 12V/1200 mA = **10 ohms** and  12V * 1200mA  = **14.4 W**. So connect a **10 ohms, 15 W** (or 2x 5 ohm, 10 W in series) **in series** with your power supply. Then it is impossible to overload it when you short the leads.

Comment: Wait so just making sure I read it right...connect a 10ohm 15w resistor to it?

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPQuaF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simple current limiter with built-in analog current level indication.*

Try adding a couple of car tail-lamps. They will reduce the power available at the electrode. If the reduction is too much try a single 21 W brake lamp. Your PSU is only rated for 14.4 W (12 x 1.2) so you wouldn't leave the lamp on deliberately but it's unlikely to suffer permanent damage.

Comment: A classic, and sometimes the classics are great.

Comment: I'm a great fan of filament bulbs for current limiting. Self-indicating, high power dissipation for their size (they safely get much hotter than resistors), when you need it they are sort-of constant current. Buy a few spares now before they become unobtainable as the world goes fully LED!

Comment: Might have to try it

Comment: Using a bulb is great ,Its much better than a resister because the cold filament has about a tenth of the resistance of the hot filament so your curve is much more ideal than the sloping line of the resister.Also you can rig it up such that the normal voltage across the bulb is low so the bulb will last a very long time .